# How to write xpath for the below cases selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]

i want to access to the span tag for both case 1 and 2 using xpath.

Answer (score 0):

**case 1 :**

```
//div[@class = 'show detail']/descendant::span
```

You may even do indexing like this :

`//div[@class = 'show detail']/descendant::span[0]`

or

```
//div[@class = 'show detail']/descendant::span[last()]
```

now use it like this :

if **python** is your binding language :

```
all_spans = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'show detail']/descendant::span")
all_spans[0] # -> first span 
all_spans[1] # -> second span
and so on..
```

**Case 2 :**

it's a direct child, you can do this :

```
//div[@class = 'show detail']/child::span
```